# Test Agent Could not Communicate with test controller

Tags: visual-studio-2013, load-testing

I have two virtual machines, with windows server 2012 R2 Operating System, on the same domain, and i have installed visual studio test controller 2013 on one of it and visual studio test agent 2013 on the other one with user account which is domain admin and have administration privileges on the two machines, also windows firewall is turned off on the two machines, and the IP of each virtual machines with its name is added to the host file in the other machine whose path is "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc", but when i configure the visual studio test agent to connect to visual studio test controller it is failed with the following error:

Failed to register this test agent with the test controller. Connection to the test controller failed because either the test controller is inaccessible or the service is not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem above i followed the following steps:
First in the controller machine

1-  Use User account which is member of administrators group to install 
and configure test controller;
2-  After installation and configuration three local created  group which are: TeamTestAgentService, TeamTestControllerAdmins, TeamTestControllerUsers you have to add the user account mentioned above to these three groups;

3-  Go to the path “C:\Program Files (x86) \Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE”, open QTController.exe.config using notepad and add to the  section this line 
; which means that the controller is listening to this ip.

4-  Re-configure Test controller.

Second in the agent machine i followed the following steps:

1-   Use the same user account (same username and password and is member of Administration group on agent machine) which you install the controller with to install the agent;

2-  Go to the path “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE” , open QTAgentService.exe.config using notepad and add to the   section this line 
 which mean that the agent is listening to this ip.

3-  Configure the Test Agent using the same user account mentioned above.